# Multiple join queries and bridge tables with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm relatively new to anything more than basic usage of NHibernate. I'm wondering if someone can help me formulate the code for the following scenario:

**Table structure**

UserProfile

UserProfile_SubTableA_Bridge

SubTableA

UserProfile_SubTableB_Bridge

SubTableB

I'm trying to construct a query that accomplishes this:

```
FetchAllNotDeleted(IEnumerable<SubTableB> SelectedA, IEnumerable<SubTableB> SelectedB)
{
  select * from UserProfile
  left join SubTable1_Bridge A
  left join SubTable2_Bridge B
  where 
  A.Id in(SelectedA)
  OR B.Id in (SelectedB)

  return Query().Future();
}
```

This seems simple enough in regular sql, but I'm not sure how to formulate this query using NHib.

What if I wanted to conditionally add the joins based on whether SelectedA or SelectedB was null? Something like:

```
if( selectedA != null ) { /* add join and restrictions for A */}
if( selectedB != null ) { /* add join and restrictions for B */}
```

I tried the following, and it's close, but it "ands" them together instead of "or"

```
if (selectedA != null)
{
var selectedIds = selectedA.Select(x => x.Id.ToString()).ToList();
query.JoinQueryOver(x => x.SubA, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).And(
        Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(
            Restrictions.In("Id", selectedIds)
        )
    );
}

if (selectedB != null)
{
    var selectedIds = selectedB.Select(x => x.Id.ToString()).ToList();
    query.JoinQueryOver(x => x.SubB, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).And(
            Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(
                Restrictions.In("Id", selectedIds)
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: I think the part I'm getting hung up on is the "OR" part of the where clause. I can write each query separately, but I can't seem to make them do a "one or the other"

Comment: Which version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: I've also added a refinement to my question

Comment: Here's what I tried. It's close, but it "ands" the where instead of "ors" them. *edit* can't post code in the comments, I'll add it to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub1Entity sub1 = null;
Sub1Entity sub2 = null;

session.QueryOver<UserProfile>()
    .JoinAlias(up => up.Sub1, () => sub1)
    .JoinAlias(up => up.Sub2, () => sub2)
    .Where(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => sub1.Id), SelectedA),
        Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => sub2.Id), SelectedB))
    .Future();
```

Update: Conditionally

```
var query = session.QueryOver<UserProfile>();
Disjunction or = null;

if( selectedA != null )
{
    Sub1Entity sub1 = null;
    query = query.JoinAlias(up => up.Sub1, () => sub1)
    or = (or ?? new Disjunction()).Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => sub1.Id), SelectedA));
}

if( selectedB != null )
{
    Sub2Entity sub2 = null;
    query = query.JoinAlias(up => up.Sub2, () => sub2)
    or = (or ?? new Disjunction()).Add(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => sub2.Id), SelectedB));
}

if (or != null)
    query = query.Where(or);

return query.Future();
```

Comment: Does JoinAlias do a Left Join?

Comment: inner join by default, but you can prepend `.JoinAlias` with `.Left` to get left joins

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this syntax before...so you check if there's an existing disjunction and then add the restriction...can you explain your restriction syntax? 

Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => sub2.Id)
specifically, this:
() => sub2.Id

Comment: `() => sub2.Id` is lambda expression. it is used to give you compiletime safe, refactore friendly, intellisense enabled syntax to express `Projections.Property("sub2.Id")` where sub2 is the alias defined in Joinalias which uses the same technic. search for lambda, type inference, expressions or linq for further infos

Comment: I'm having an issue with your suggestion...this line fails:
query = query.Add(or);
add isn't an available option...all I have are options like And, AndNot, AndRestrictionOn, etc